# Passing props through nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating an upload page. And there will be three interfaces that are divided between diferent components.

Upload page: [image]

Uploading page: [image]

Uploaded page: [image]

The issue is that I want to create the formData in one component, make the request in the uploading comp and the response will be displayed at the last one... But I'm not quite sure the best way to do so, because these components are quite away from one another...

I made a diagram to exemplify:
[image]

Don't know if it helps, but here's some code of these components:
Body:

```
 const Body = () => {
      return (
        <div className="main-body">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<UploadPage />} />
            <Route path="/uploading" element={<LoadingPage />} />
            <Route path="/uploaded" element={<UploadedSuccess />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

UploadPage:

```
const UploadPage = () => {
  return (
    <Box maxWidth={500} maxHeight={650}>
      <h1>Upload your image</h1>
      <h2>File should be Jpeg, Png</h2>
      <DropZoneCompWithImage noClickAccept={true} noDragAccept={false} /> //one of the compoennts that creates the formdata
      <p
        style={{
          color: "#BDBDBD",
          fontFamily: "'Poppins', sans-serif",
          marginTop: "-8px",
        }}
      >
        Or
      </p>
      <DropZoneButton /> //other component that creates a formData
    </Box>
  );
};
```

First CreateForm Comp:

```
const DropZoneCompWithImage = ({ noClickAccept, noDragAccept }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const onDrop = React.useCallback(async (acceptFiles) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", acceptFiles[0]);

    navigate("/uploading");
  }, []);
...
```

Second CreateForm comp:

```
const DropZoneButton = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const onDrop = React.useCallback(async (acceptFiles) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", acceptFiles[0]);
      navigate("/uploading");
  }, []);
...
```

Uploading comp (request):

```
const LoadingPage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function postData() {
      const data = await api.post("/post", formData, {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      });
    }
    setTimeout(() => navigate("/uploaded"), 2000);
  }, []);
...
```

Uploaded comp (response):

```
const UploadedSuccess = () => {
  return (
    <Box maxWidth={600} maxHeight={750}>
      <div className="upload-sucess-container">
        <img
          src={GreenCheck}
          alt="Green Check Icon"
          className="green-check-button"
        />
        <h1>Uploaded Successefully!</h1>
        <img src={ExemploImg} alt="Exemple" className="image-uploaded" />
        <div className="link-uploaded">
          <p>link</p>
          <button>Copiar Link</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I must admit that I'm quite lost of what to do...

Comment: Read about `useContext`, it might help you. https://medium.com/@devluispereira/react-context-api-typescript-507eec884549

Comment: @mathiasfk thanks man! Worked just fine!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass props to another component in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69921930/how-to-pass-props-to-another-component-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

I made it happen with useContext, thanks to mathias tip!